# Disable command button until specific option buttons are selected

Tags: excel, vba

I have a UserForm "HRMForm" with 4 option buttons. Users must select at least 2 of these option buttons to proceed. Until this requirement is fulfilled, I want the Submit command button to be disabled.

I have included the names of each option button and the command button :
1. optHRMCM
2. optHRMLI
3. optHRMPM
4. optHRMBE
5. Command button - btnHRMSubmit

My current code words. However, after the user selects the correct options and the submit button is enabled, if they click off these option buttons the submit button remains enabled. How can I code it to go back to being disabled?

```
Private Sub optHRMLI_Click()

If Me.optHRMCM And Me.optHRMLI Then
   btnHRMSubmit.Enabled = True
End If

If Me.optHRMCM And Me.optHRMPM Then
   btnHRMSubmit.Enabled = True
End If

If Me.optHRMCM And Me.optHRMBE Then
   btnHRMSubmit.Enabled = True
End If

If Me.optHRMLI And Me.optHRMPM Then
   btnHRMSubmit.Enabled = True
End If

If Me.optHRMLI And Me.optHRMBE Then
   btnHRMSubmit.Enabled = True
End If

If Me.optHRMPM And Me.optHRMBE Then
   btnHRMSubmit.Enabled = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think the option buttons will allow you to select multiple options? Do you mean checkboxes?

Comment: Hi RCL thanks for your reply, I have put them into separate Frame's so they work independently :)

Comment: Ah make sense :) bad assumption on my end.

Comment: Place code in sheet* (edited) with a private scope, you can call it by assigning it as a macro from the button.

Comment: Hi Riley, please could you explain this? I am very sorry my VBA skills are very limited!

Comment: You already have it as a private scope (`Private Sub optHRMLI_Click()`) place it in whatever sheet you have the button in.

Comment: Also do you want the submit button disabled or not able to run the code inside? You could instead have a message pop up saying that the user needs to select certain options if they haven't yet and pressed the button.

Comment: Hi Riley, thank you for your reply. A message popup without the inside code running would be great. Is there a way I can do this? :)

Comment: You can use the function: `MsgBox ("You have not selected enough options!", 0, "Error")`
 Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function

Comment: Thank you, Riley, this is great. For some reason, with my current code, it disables the command button when I click on the option button optHRMLI and I assume that is because of where I have positioned the code. Do you have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the code you need. Just replace the names in it and this is inside the userform.

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
  countOptions
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
countOptions
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
countOptions
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton4_Click()
countOptions
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

  CommandButton1.Enabled = False

End Sub

Sub countOptions()
 Dim cntrl As Control
 Dim Count As Integer
 Count = 0
 For Each cntrl In UserForm1.Controls

    If TypeOf cntrl Is msforms.OptionButton Then

       If cntrl = True Then
         Count = Count + 1
       End If

    End If
 Next

 If Count >= 2 Then
  CommandButton1.Enabled = True
 End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, RCL! For the last sub (sub count0topions()) is this a module? or do I place it somewhere on my userform? Many thanks and apologies for my uselessness haha

Comment: it can be a module or inside the userform but in this example it was inside the userform.